# Как программно понять о конце списка айтемов в recycler view?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Именно событие когда появляется эта дуга, как на прикрепленной фотографии[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Можно проверить в самом адаптере

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    if(position == (getItemCount() - 1)){
        //logic
     }
}
```

2) Или в коде фрагмента/активити

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager.class.cast(recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
                int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                int lastVisible = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                boolean endHasBeenReached = lastVisible + VISIBLE_ITEMS_COUNT >= totalItemCount;
                if (totalItemCount > 0 && endHasBeenReached) {
                   //logic
                }
            }
        });
```

Мне симпотичней первый вариант

Comment: Мне нужно показать кнопку для прогрузки следующих сообщений(та что сверху, только появляться она должна своевременно). Поэтому, мне подойдет второй вариант. Откуда взять значение константы VISIBLE_ITEMS_COUNT?

Comment: VISIBLE_ITEMS_COUNT - количество элементов, которые видимы на экране. Быть может вам тут нужно заюзать footer?

Comment: Если вам не сложно сейчас привести пример его использования, то буду очень благодарен
Ну и, конечно же, за выше предоставленный ответ благодарю.

Comment: Думаю, скорее header. Кнопка же вверху

Comment: Вот тут хороший пример и хэдэра и футера http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/10/adding-header-and-footer-layouts-for.html